# select current link

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i select the current link via jquery if I have a div like this:

```
<div id='navigation'>
  <a href='users/home'>home</a> |
  <a href='projects/browse'>home</a>
  <a href='discussions/browse'>home</a>
  <a href='search/dosearch'>home</a>
</div>
```

Note I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation a").click( function(event)
    {
       var clicked = $(this); // jQuery wrapper for clicked element
       // ... click-specific code goes here ...
       clicked.addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

But when I click on a link it selects a link and adds the class .selected but it reloads the page in order to navigate to a page and then it all disappears. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how your div is, maybe you could leave blank lines before and after your html and indent it with at least 4 spaces, so that it is displyed correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href; // The URL of the page we're looking at
    $('#navigation a').each(function() {
        if (loc.indexOf(this.href) !== -1) { // If the URL contains the href of the anchor
            $(this).addClass('selected'); // Mark it as selected
        }
    });
});
```

It basically loops over the navigation items, and if the URL of the current page contains the href of the anchor, it adds the class `selected` to the anchor.

Comment: Yes but it will still reload the page because the default event attached on the link will still be activated.

Comment: Right, but the question (as I understood it) was how to select the current link, and not how to stay on the current page. I don't know if I'm right, though.

Comment: @Moff - You rule man! This totally works. Awesome piece of code! Thanks a lott!!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, take the event from your `click()` callback arguments and use `e.preventDefault();` (see [there](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#fn)).

Or `return false`.

Or add a `target='_blank'` attribute to your links so that they open the link in some other page or tab, if you still want the link to be opened by the browser somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation a").click( function(event)
    {
       var clicked = $(this); // jQuery wrapper for clicked element
       // ... click-specific code goes here ...
       clicked.addClass('selected');
       return false;
    });
});
```

Don't forget to `return false`!